# JMeter 1 Thread group performs 10% of other Thread group

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, web-testing

I am testing web app. Basically I have 1 thread group (lets call them affiliates) who on average need to perform 2.5 requests per second (each request being a request for an imaginary advert). The second thread group (end users) needs "click" on 10% of these adverts requested by the Affiliates.

I have the following setup:

[Test setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZKXP.png)

Each Thread group has a ramp up time of 1(s).
The constant timer for the first thread group (Affiliates) is 400ms (1second / 2.5clicks = 1 click per 0.4 seconds = 1 click per 400ms). If I have understood correctly this should make sure that each affiliate should click once every 400ms.

The second thread group has a constant timer of 4000ms (since the timer is a delay then 4000ms makes should result in 10% requests of the first thread group).

When testing with one user, the results are fine, as I increase the users however (for example at 150 users per thread group (300 total users)) the results are no longer AdClick 10% of AdRequests.

Running my test for 1 minute I get the following:
AdsRequest = 4695 samples
AdsClicked = 1568 samples

AdsClicked should be about 470 samples

So my question is: How can I set up my test to constantly have 10% samples of AdRequests for Adclicked, irregardless of how many users are currently using the system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your setup is not very correct in terms of Constant Timers location. According to [Timers Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers):

   > Note that timers are processed **before** each sampler in the scope in which they are found; if there are several timers in the same scope, all the timers will be processed **before each** sampler.
   >
   > Timers are only processed in conjunction with a sampler. A timer which is not in the same scope as a sampler will not be processed at all. 
   >   To apply a timer to a single sampler, **add the timer as a child element of the sampler**. The timer will be applied before the sampler is executed. To apply a timer after a sampler, either add it to the next sampler, or add it as the child of a Test Action Sampler.
2. If you need to manipulate throughput (requests per second) it is better to consider [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)
3. As you don't have guarantee of exact 10% match using the Timers for this requirement:

   > irregardless of how many users are currently using the system

   you can consider moving both samplers under single Thread Group and use [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) or [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) to make your `AdsClicked` request to be exactly 10% of `AdRequests`. See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for more details on the approach.